# Can scanf() be used to declare a variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, declaration, scanf

So, I just have a simple code. I was asked to verify how many times it would run.

```
int i = 0;
int s = 0;
int b = 0;
while(i < 10){
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d" ,&x);
    s += x;
    if(x > b){
        b = x;
    }
    i++;
```

I stated it would never run due to **x** not being declared. I was told I was wrong and it was declared.

My question is can scanf() declare a variable? Or would you say the only way this code would run is if **x** is declared?

Comment: This snippet is obviously incomplete; among other things, the terminating `}` for the `while` loop is missing, so who knows what it does after it increments `i`.  Either you've made a mistake in cutting and pasting, or the person who gave you mangled it.  So it's entirely possible that `x` was declared in the original code, although you wouldn't know it.  Having said all that, the loop depends on the value of `i`; account for how `i` is updated in the loop, and you have your answer.

Answer (score 4):

x must be declared, your example is wrong, but you can use a compound literal inside scanf call:

```
scanf("%d" , &(int){0} ) ;    //(int){0} is a compound literal
                              //and its address is passed to the function
```

And scanf will write a number into that variable, the only problem is you cannot access it as you don't have its address. If you have a function that returned the address of that compound literal, you could then use it.

Answer (score 2):

In this code snippet variable x is not declared. The compiler shall issue an error. In the `scanf` `&x` is an argument expression. It is not a declaration and may not be a declaration.

If to assume that x was declared and that after statement

i++;

there is a closing brace then the loop will be iteratated 10 times.:)

It seems that the purpose of the code is to calculate the sum of 10 integers and to find the maximim positive integer among them.

But in any case it is a very bad code and it does not deserve to be discussed.:)

Comment: Disagree about: "bad code and it does not deserve to be discussed"  SO is not so much for code that is working, but for code that is bad.

Comment: @chux Ther is nothing to discuss except to say that it is a bad code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running it to see what happens?

It won't compile, both because x isn't declared and because a closing curly brace is missing at the end.

Comment: Yes I ran, and I got the error x is not declared, and then a warning that s was not used. I expected this, but had someone say it would work.